# Converting responseObject base64 encoded string to UIImage

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to send an image with PHP (on server side) to my iOS app, so that I can display it in a UIImageView.

My server side code is:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); //if your data is format jpeg

$username = $_POST['username'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
$base64string =     base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/".$username."/".$count."/".$username."file".$count.".jpeg"));
echo $base64string;

?>
```

I receive the image with this code in my iOS app:

```
NSString * uploadURL = @"http://192.168.1.4/getimage.php";

NSLog(@"uploadImageURL: %@", uploadURL);

NSString *queryStringss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", uploadURL];
                queryStringss = [queryStringss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/plain"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/jpeg"];

NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *usernameEncoded = [marker.title stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": usernameEncoded, @"count": [object valueForKey:@"count"]};

[manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
       NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:responseObject options:0];
       image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData scale:300/2448];
           [self.view addSubview:image];
       }
   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
   }];
```

When I run the code - it hits the failure block with an error that reads as the base64 encoded "string" (image) that I am sending:

```
2015-12-03 01:19:15.655 sneek[6261:1952572] Error: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAYAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAMwKADAAQAAAABAAAJkAAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+/8AAEQgJkAzAAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tr

... (very long) ...

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `AFJSONResponseSerializer` even though it's not JSON. Sure, you've overridden `acceptableContentTypes`, but that doesn't stop it from trying to parse JSON in the response.

I'd use `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and then lose the `acceptableContentTypes`.

By the way, I wouldn't use `image/jpeg` for a base64-encoded response, because it's text, not a jpeg. If you're going to return a raw base64-string, you might use `application/text` or something like that.

Or, better, change your PHP to actually return JSON (because that will make it easier to parse the response) and stay with `AFJSONResponseSerializer` (but lose the `acceptableContentTypes` once you fix the header) and then you can grab the base64 string from `response[@"image"]`.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
$base64string =     base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/".$username."/".$count."/".$username."file".$count.".jpeg"));
echo json_encode(array("image" => $base64string));

?>
```

Or, use `AFImageResponseSerializer` and change the PHP to return the image:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); //if your data is format jpeg

$username = $_POST['username'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
$contents = file_get_contents("images/".$username."/".$count."/".$username."file".$count.".jpeg"));
echo $contents;

?>
```

Comment: thank you trying your second suggestion now...wasn't sure how to implement your first suggestion on iOS side.

Comment: The true JSON approach? You can then grab the base64 string with `response["image"]` and then decode that.

Comment: i changed php to what you suggested...and i am going to update what my iOS code looks like right now...I am also getting a new error but I think I am further along now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: im gonna try your json approach now that i have your explanation thanks - if that doesnt work i will update my question so you can see what is happening...thanks